# List of keywords as features

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I'm new to machine learning, being this the first time I'm involved in a project in the area. I have a dataset of news articles and have extracted the keywords present on the news title such as `['china factory activity shrinks', 'first time', '2 years']`. Note, the list size varies.

I would like to use this data in my features, but I don't know how and what is the best way to extract features based on a list of keywords.

Since the keywords cannot be converted to a categorical value, I think I can't use OneHotEnconder, but I'm not 100% certain. Is bag-of-words or TF-IDF viable possiblity? How can I encode this keywods to numerical values maintaining some meaningful information to the model?

Comment: You may use Word2Vec to vectorize the tokens.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I have looked to word2Vec, but I'm just wondering what application it may have to the model, besides the word similarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, of course we can use TF-IDF or bag of words. The easiest way is to build a separate TFIDF transformer for every group of keywords and then combine them together using `FeatureUnion`. Just make sure the custom `tokenizer` only filters out the keywords in each group that you're looking at.

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

corpus = [
    "china factory activity shrinks some text here",
    "first time some text here",
    "2 years some text here",
    "combining first time and 2 years here.",
    "adding china factory activity first but doesn't match exactly"
]

# custom tokenizers

keywords1 = lambda x: [x for x in x.split() if x in ["china", "factory", "activity", "shrinks"]]
keywords2 = lambda x: [x for x in x.split() if x in ["first", "time"]]
keywords3 = lambda x: [x for x in x.split() if x in ["2", "years"]]

combined_features = FeatureUnion([
    ('kwd1', TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=keywords1)),
    ('kwd2', TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=keywords2)),
    ('kwd3', TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=keywords3))
])

pipeline = Pipeline([('bow', combined_features)])
output_corpus = pipeline.fit_transform(corpus)
```

For the deep-learning approach, I would recommend a similar kind of pattern so that the embedding learned from each group would have a different semantic meaning from another group. You'll just need to ensure that the tokenizer only considers the keywords from each group when it is processed. If you're using a pre-build word embedding; you'll just have a filter before it goes into each embedding so that it doesn't "leak" into another topic.

Example using Keras:

```py
from keras import layers
from keras.models import Model
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

def custom_sequence_tokenizer(txt, vocab):
    vocab_mapper = dict([(word, idx+1) for idx, word in enumerate(vocab)])
    text_split = [vocab_mapper.get(x, 0) for x in txt.split() if x in vocab]
    return text_split

keywords1 = pad_sequences([custom_sequence_tokenizer(x, ["china", "factory", "activity", "shrinks"]) for x in corpus], padding='post', maxlen=10)
keywords2 = pad_sequences([custom_sequence_tokenizer(x, ["first", "time"]) for x in corpus], padding='post', maxlen=10)
keywords3 = pad_sequences([custom_sequence_tokenizer(x, ["2", "years"]) for x in corpus], padding='post', maxlen=10)

input_count1 = layers.Input(shape=(10,), name='in1')
input_count2 = layers.Input(shape=(10,), name='in2')
input_count3 = layers.Input(shape=(10,), name='in3')

# input size is reflection of the vocab size
embed1 = layers.Embedding(5, 8)(input_count1)
embed2 = layers.Embedding(3, 8)(input_count2)
embed3 = layers.Embedding(3, 8)(input_count3)

combine = layers.Concatenate()([embed1, embed2, embed3])

model = Model(inputs=[input_count1, input_count2, input_count3], outputs=combine)
output = model.predict({
    'in1': keywords1,
    'in2': keywords2,
    'in3': keywords3,
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll be looking to this then.

Comment: what is a recomended method I should follow to encode the result from the TF-IDF scores from the group of keywords?

Comment: That's really up to you and the domain tbh. You could just us a naive bag-of-words per group of keywords to start off with and depending on how that goes expand from there